# Should proofs include a third “context” column?

Tags: secondary-education, proofs, usa

Proofs, or any mathematical derivation, appearing in any real setting, such as a book or textbook or talk, or even when we're teaching it in class, includes a great deal of surrounding explanation. But when we ask students to regurgitate proofs, we ask for what is merely the skeletal core of the proof in this rib-like two column format. At the very least, it seems to me, proofs ought to have three columns, including a new multi-row lefthand column that describes (at least) the approach being taken in that section of the proof. By "multi-row" I mean that the proposed new lefthand "row" can encompass multiple rows of the basic two-column proof. The resulting format would look like this:

```
    =================|===============|==============
      What we're     |   <c=<c       |  Reflective Property
       up to in      |  tABC~=tDEF   |  SAS
       this section  |    etc...     |  etc...
    =================|===============|==============
      What we're     |    etc...     |  etc...
       up to in      |    etc...     |  etc...
       this section  |    etc...     |  etc...
```

The context would, I think, largely reflect the reasoning and planning that went into (goes into) the proof, and would commonly, I think, end up representing lemmas that participate in the larger proof. One could say that these lemmas ought to be rolled off into prior proofs of their own, and I would agree. But we do not provide a way, in geometry, of naming and organizing proofs usefully so that prior short proofs (technically lemmas) can be looked up and referred to easily.

Because we do not have a clear naming scheme for proofs, we cannot call upon them as one would functions in a programming language. Indeed, one might wonder why student of geometry aren't being taught geometry like one would teach a programming language: Here's a bunch of functions (lemmas) you can use, and here's how to use them. We do do this for some things, like the triangle congruence lemmas (SAS etc), and for some logical rationales (CPCTC, etc), but the dozen random theorems (lemmas) regarding parallelograms, mid segments, and so on aren't ready-to-hard functions with clear naming, so we end up re-deriving/proving them in the middle of other proofs, which makes the proofs into these long-winded, un-memorable and ultimately unwieldy things.

The three-column format I'm proposing at least offers a way to internally organize proofs into logical segments so that even without addressing the problem of the previous paragraph, at least there is a a way of making the substructure explicit.

Comment: I'm just happy if I can get the students to write complete sentences with actual words.

Comment: Actually, I literally just found this, highly relevant comment: https://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2013/10/16/two-column-proofs-that-two-column-proofs-are-terrible/comment-page-1/amp/

Comment: The rigid 2-column proof format along with abbreviations for axioms or already proven theorems is characteristic for American high schools. In other parts of the world they use free-flow text form. Your three-column proposal is of the same "8 steps to solve a linear equation" sort of schemes that American edu-consultants like so much because they can copyright them and sell them as a "method".

Comment: As a Russian, I don't understand the question. What columns, what table, what the hell are you even talking about?

Comment: @CrabMan How to Russian students learn to present proofs? Let's stick to geometry proofs, for the sake of having a sensible comparison. One could argue that any derivation is a sort of "proof", but I'm talking here about geometric, not algebraic "proofs". Maybe these aren't taught at all in Russian schools, which would in-and-of-itself be interesting. Or maybe they are just rolled in with any other sort of derivation. (Although proof has a sense of generalization that is not exactly the same as a derivation.)

Comment: Raciquel: Yes, I know. In fact that’s exactly what I said: “ Proofs, or any mathematical derivation, appearing in any real setting, such as a book or textbook or talk, or even when we're teaching it in class, includes a great deal of surrounding explanation. But when we ask students to regurgitate proofs, we ask for what is merely the skeletal core of the proof in this rib-like two column format. …”

Comment: Well, then do not ask for proofs to be in the rib-like two column format - problem solved.

Comment: No no. That’s not the point. I think I got off on the wrong foot seeming to criticize the 2column format. It makes sense (in whatever format) to have a conclusion and rationale for each step. What seems to be missing as taught is an explicit indication of the plan. We talk about the plan (and goal structure) but don’t write it down anywhere when we teach. My idea of a third colum was just to encourage, for that particular format, explicating the plan/goal structure.

Comment: The "basic two-column format" is peculiar to elementary education in the US. It is certainly never used by practicing mathematicians, at least not since duality was assimilated and the need to prove every result in projective geometry twice, once for points once for lines, was abandoned. It should be purged from US education too. It does not aid in teaching careful thinking or writing convincing arguments.

Comment: @DanFox Just saying that they should be purged isn't very useful. What should replace them for organizing reasoning? Music has musical notation. But a middle/high school student trying to explain their reasoning -- assuming, for the sake of this argument, that they have reasoning (which does sometimes happen! :-) --  generally blats it out all over the page. Learning to organize argument in some manner is useful, like learning to indent your program usefully. And I do think that having a consistent format is useful. Just, to my mind, the 2CF doesn't offer as much support as one needs.

Comment: I have no idea about that format, but when I was at high school in Italy proofs (both for geometry and analysis) were taught exactly as they are taught at the university level, so the format was that of free text.

Answer (score 3):

I think maybe the correct answer to this question is something simple like

**Sure, do something else if you like.**

I also recommend reading [this question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/is-there-any-evidence-about-the-effectiveness-of-table-proofs-in-pre-college-m?rq=1) because the good answer there may give you some insights into how imposing a structure on proofs can help and how it can hurt.

Answer (score 3):

> OP: What seems to be missing as taught is an explicit indication of the plan.

Even though this is far afield from your concentration on geometry, it
illustrates your point. Michael Sipser's text,
*Introduction to the Theory of Computation,*
includes many "proof idea" sections prior to launching into each formal proof.
I've taught from this text and this really works.
Such "proof idea" thumbnails can be presented in any format (Sipser just
uses prose paragraphs), a 3rd column if you prefer.

[image: Cover]